# Speaking only in terms of time and other costs (downsides) to the agents involved, what are the failure states of SO matching engine?

Tags: discussion

I view SO as a matching engine between problem posters and responders.

User A has two actions:
i) posts problem P to SO (cheap, quick, done)
ii) continue to do random research to solve problem P (expensive, but ongoing, happens anyway)

Often a response to a problem P by some User B will be "I recommend action ii)". Which is quite strange thing to recommend since it is basically like a matching engine matching non-crossed bid and ask where the participants say too-expensive/too-cheap and get annoyed with each other for the matching engine wasting time.

What is the goal here? Surely the proper way to deal with this is to let these questions sit on the market untouched? Why match questions with individuals who are just going to say "don't use SO".

I could give many other weird examples of failure states of the matching engine but I will keep it to this one example here and cover others in separate questions in meat.

A user below has asked me to INCREASE SPEND on this question already by providing an exemplar. I do not mind too much since the effort is bounded however I worry about over-fitting to the exemplar.

Example:

Q: How do you dig a Hole using a Half Spade in EarthLanguage?
R: I recommend reading the Hole docs.

Let's assume that the poster does have the ability to read the docs and discover an answer in some finite time. This *bounds* the cost but that is all. OBVIOUSLY the poster is coming to SO to post something quickly in the hopes of a lower cost path to a solution while they continue to read and look elsewhere to figure out their problem. So we might say the poster is asking "I'm looking to buy X for less than 100 bucks" and then someone response "how about 100 bucks?".

I would agree that telling someone a) this is solvable in the docs b) showing them how to find the solution are both helpful and good. But then is this answer not a meta-answer and the whole thing belongs in Meta?

Comment: Are you asking why we close questions rather than leave them be for someone to eventually come by and answer anyway? or,

Comment: @RobertLongson What kind of concrete example? And in what ways will it make things clearer? I worry reduce an class of instances to an example will lead responders to overfit to the examplar which is definitely something I worry about.

Comment: This is a lot of syntax.  Maybe to distill it similar to what @KevinB was saying, are you asking why folks bother curating/moderating posts at all versus just answering all of them?

Comment: "*What is the goal here?*" As stated by the tour: "*With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming.*"

Comment: *"posts problem P to SO (cheap, quick, done"* Yeah, but it shouldn't be quick or cheap. Such questions are likely to be downvoted and closed very quickly. They are not very useful additions to our repository.

Comment: Ideally, users on SO shouldn't be the ones matching the problem to the solution. This task should be done by your favourite search engine. If the search engine fails, you can post a new question. It's still possible that you were searching wrong terms and someone can point you to an existing answer on Stack Overflow. If that question hasn't been answered here yet, then your new question might get the answer and become the target for future researchers.

Comment: @Makoto that is a good question. I guess I am getting at the fact that posts are ranked by (post, responder) pairs and I would just let posts that seem bad to most just simply get ignored, not matched with negative responders who implicitly seek to increase the net expected cost of asker.

Comment: @Dharman sorry, why shouldn't it be cheap quick done etc? This is the whole point of building services. This is why we use google etc. It *works* and is cheap (at least up front). Please note that *cheap* means only COST. Let us not use it as a pejorative like people might in regular use to mean "badly made".

Comment: @KevinB Closing questions makes sense usually as a reason is given. My case I am asking about responses that appear to simply push the asker away, increase their cost with an increase in probability of finding an answer. If a child asks "where to read about why is the sky blue" and the response "read the docs" it sort of feels like a missed opportunity since they were asking about where to find that in the docs and they already knew the could just read linearly until they found it.

Comment: It should not be quick and cheap because you are expected to spend as much time as needed before posting the question doing research, fixing grammar, preparing MCVE if needed, making sure all information is present in the question, etc.

Comment: Comments telling askers to read the docs can and should be flagged. It's not appropriate to do so. The whole idea is to have the information here, not in the docs.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what this question is about anymore. Are you asking why some people add comments telling people to read the docs? That's simply not allowed and can be flagged. If that's not what you are asking, then what are you asking?

Comment: @Dharman Re: "read the docs" that is very helpful to hear. Thank you. I was not sure if that was the way it should happen or not.

Comment: I think I am also realising that most people don't even know what "downside" is per se or think like that. I am using technical language that probably is out of context on meta. For those interesting, I think of this as kind of gambles in time. We are all gambling on different actions when we try to do things to solve a problem in a particular order.

Comment: Downvoted (without reading any further) because the Title is completely elliptic/cryptic/incomprehensible... / Quote: "*Speaking only in terms of time and other costs (downsides) to the agents involved, what are the failure states of SO matching engine?*"

Comment: Re the words *cost*, *agents*, *failure states*, *non-crossed bid*, *sit on the market untouched*, *increase spend*, *effort is bounded*, *over-fitting*, *bounds the cost*, *lower cost path*, *reduce a class of instances*, *posts are ranked by (post, responder) pairs*, *the net expected cost of the asker*, *increase their cost*, *all gambling on different action*, *interactions are matches*,

Comment: cont' - *a very zoomed out notion of reward*, *[reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning) system*, *response with a higher price than my offer*, *tautologically the same as saying*, *solve the problem at cost*, *take your epsilon loss*, *think in terms of ROI*, *impervious to various kinds of misinterpretation*, *problems that are costly*, etc.: We are not used to that kind of language here :-) For all we know, it is just word salad.

Comment: More importantly, we don't have any idea of what you are talking about. Stack Overflow is a kind of knowledge market, but this has not been talked about at all since the 2008-2010 time frame (e.g., I think it was talked about in that way in some of early podcast episodes). (And the "Stack Exchange" name possibly as a pun on both "[stock exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_exchange)" and [the hyphen site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts_Exchange).)

Comment: Perhaps write a blog post where you include definitions of all the parts of that market, as you see it? The intended audience could be the presumed [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) regulars. (In the old [Usenet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usenet) days (before [AOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOL) destroyed it), the main exchange, as I saw it, was *effort*: the asker provided more than the bare minimum (for an interesting question), had the courtesy

Comment: cont' - to not ask duplicate (beginner) questions (had checked the [FAQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ) first) and put in the effort to provide an [MRE](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)). The answerer put in the *effort* to provide a *comprehensive* answer, not just suggestions or throwing unspecific links. The main long-lasting value was carefully crafted FAQs.)

Comment: "Surely the proper way to deal with this is to let these questions sit on the market untouched?" No. Flooding the site with trash makes it hard to find good questions, which is the primary purpose of the site. It's the age-old misunderstanding, assuming that SO is about 1:1 matchups between questions and answers so OP can solve their specific problem in isolation. Actually, the "market" isn't about helping OP, it's about helping the thousands (millions, in some cases) of future visitors that have the same problem as OP. It's a repository of knowledge, a bit like Wikipedia but in Q&A format.

Comment: Since you seem to want to speak on a technical level, the idea with SO is to solve the matching problem in O(1) rather than O(n). You're proposing (a flawed) micro-optimization to a fundamentally ineffiicient algorithm.

Comment: It's not a market. Beggars are not choosers. PS "I am using technical language that probably is out of context on meta." More to the point, you are being purposefully obtuse. You are also rambling while you are doing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The goal is to create a knowledge repository; it's not a help desk. So framing it as a cost-benefit analysis with respect to time spent looking for answers is already misguided because **Stack Overflow doesn't care how much time you spend looking for an answer** to your question, i.e. the OP's "cost" never comes into the equation. In fact, some might say, you should spend as much time as possible *before* posting your question so that your question is useful for *future users*.

Comment: This is a great answer. SO simply does not care about user time. And encourage wastage. Anyone who wants to build something better can probably do so with some knowledge of SEO. "All" you have to do is train on a lot of existing content and then provide a more coherent matching engine that aims to create win win situations. For now, we have SO with it's left tail of toxic interactions for the Original Posters.

Comment: Basically, the take away of this (admittedly extreme take) is that one should *never* OP on SO. They might not want you to die before finishing a post, but anything up to that is ok.

Answer (score 21):

> I view SO as a matching engine between problem posters and responders.

That's not what SO is at all.

SO is a public knowledge repository of programming problems, posed as questions and answers.

If you have a unique programming problem that's well identified (so it can be found by future users, and can be reproduced so answerers can make sure they provide the right answer), you can ask it here, and other users can answer it. The question asker provides substantial value here, as they bring valuable items to the table, but are expected to do substantial research too, as are the question answerers.

The goal here is the knowledge repository, that everyone can find the answers to their problem without needing to reask the same questions. The fact that you can get helped too if you have a good question is a nice bonus, nothing more.

If you have a vague debugging question where we can only guess possible answers and suggest debugging approaches, well, that doesn't fit into this "public repository of knowledge" at all. So users are bound to be met with a "do your research", duplicate of "how to debug" or closure as "lacks a minimal reproducible example". That's how it is. Expecting us to "just answer them" because it would be more time effective for you is completely unrealistic.

If you view SO as some sort of free consultant matching service, well, you're bound to have a bad time here.

I've also never seen someone say "don't use SO". They say "don't use SO for questions like this".

Comment: This is what a matching engine is. Interactions are matches. I mean this in the most zoomed out general sense with a very zoomed out notion of reward. Think of this as someone engineering a Reinforcement Learning system.

The other point is that one persons vague question is another persons specific question. But all the people who think its vague show up first and you have to work hard to protect your question against them.

Comment: On the other hand, the math site is quite a bit better. Possibly because the context is more clear.

Comment: I suspect I have lost you on the matching engine. If you response with a higher price than my offer, I am saying that is tautologically the same as saying "do not use it". If I know I can solve the problem at cost X and you tell me to "go spend X to solve the problem AFTER I have now spent (X + epsilon) by posting to SO (that is cost epsilon) ... that is saying "go away and take your epsilon loss". Many developers probably do not think in terms of ROI but that is the way to view it.

Comment: So it sounds like, from the responses, that SO is aiming to be a site where a user spends a lot of time crafting a very precise question that is impervious to various kinds of misinterpretation (allowing for some iterative feedback) and has an answer that is low cost.

Problems that are costly to make precise, or to protect from being seen as too vague, are effectively inadmissable problems from a SO perspective. I mean inadmissable in a math sense ... like not-viable from a cost/payoff perspective.

Comment: SO is no more viable from a cost/payoff perspective for the asker than for the answerer, that's not the point. The real "cost/payoff" is when you type in a question on Google, and find a clear SO question about it, with a good answer, and both asking and answering are about paying it forward, contributing so others can benefit. Questions don't need to be easy to ask, no more than it is easy to write a Wikipedia article. And answers often need to be high-effort as well, as if there was a cheap answer, it'd be easier to not write the questions and look for it yourself.